# Aerospike aql Syntax error near token - Make sure string values are enclosed in quotes

Tags: aerospike

I'm trying to delete the records from aeropike datastore set.
I'm using the query language given [here](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/tools/aql).

But looks like the query has syntax error.I've given below the query and respective error.

```
Aerospike Query Client
Version 3.13.0.1
C Client Version 4.1.6
Copyright 2012-2016 Aerospike. All rights reserved.
aql> set  TIMEOUT 100000
aql> delete from test.User
Syntax error near token -  'delete from test.User'
Make sure string values are enclosed in quotes.
Type " aql --help " from console or simply "help" from within the aql-prompt.

aql> delete from 'test.User'
Syntax error near token -  'delete from 'test.User''
Make sure string values are enclosed in quotes.
Type " aql --help " from console or simply "help" from within the aql-prompt.

aql> truncate test.User

ERROR: 404: COMMAND NOT FOUND : truncate
aql> truncate test User

ERROR: 404: COMMAND NOT FOUND : truncate
aql> truncate ns

ERROR: 404: COMMAND NOT FOUND : truncate

aql> select '_id' from test.User
+-----------+
| _id       |
+-----------+
| "Dave-02" |
| "Dave-01" |
+-----------+
2 rows in set (1.413 secs)

aql> delete from test.User where '_id'="Dave-01"
Unsupported command format with token -  ''_id''
Make sure string values are enclosed in quotes.
Type " aql --help " from console or simply "help" from within the aql-prompt.


    aql>  show namespaces
    +------------+
    | namespaces |
    +------------+
    | "test"     |
    | "bar"      |
    +------------+
    2 rows in set (0.001 secs)
    OK

    aql> show sets
    +------------------+--------+----------------+---------+-------------------+--------------+-------------------+--------------+------------+
    | disable-eviction | ns     | set-enable-xdr | objects | stop-writes-count | set          | memory_data_bytes | truncate_lut | tombstones |
    +------------------+--------+----------------+---------+-------------------+--------------+-------------------+--------------+------------+
    | "false"          | "test" | "use-default"  | 0       | 0                 | "UserRecord" | 0                 | 0            | 0          |
    | "false"          | "bar"  | "use-default"  | 1       | 0                 | "UserRecord" | 1230              | 0            | 0          |
    +------------------+--------+----------------+---------+-------------------+--------------+-------------------+--------------+------------+
    2 rows in set (0.000 secs)
    OK
```

Any idea what is wrong in my query.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
aql> insert into ns1.user (pk, name, age) values (1, 'Raj', 24)
OK, 1 record affected.

aql> insert into ns1.user (pk, name, age) values (2, 'Kumar', 24)
OK, 1 record affected.

aql> select * from ns1.user
+---------+-----+
| name    | age |
+---------+-----+
| "Raj"   | 24  |
| "Kumar" | 24  |
+---------+-----+
2 rows in set (0.039 secs)

OK

aql> delete from ns1.user where pk = 1
OK, 1 record affected.

aql> select * from ns1.user
+---------+-----+
| name    | age |
+---------+-----+
| "Kumar" | 24  |
+---------+-----+
1 row in set (0.038 secs)

OK
```

Extending the example further (also showing with key_send set to true) for ease of understanding, showing how truncate works.

```
aql> set key_send true
KEY_SEND = true
aql> insert into ns1.user (pk, name, age) values (1, 'Raj', 24)
OK, 1 record affected.

aql> insert into ns1.user (pk, name, age) values (2, 'Kumar', 25)
OK, 1 record affected.

aql> select * from ns1.user
+----+---------+-----+
| PK | name    | age |
+----+---------+-----+
| 1  | "Raj"   | 24  |
| 2  | "Kumar" | 25  |
+----+---------+-----+
2 rows in set (0.037 secs)

OK

aql> truncate ns1.user
OK

aql> select * from ns1.user
0 rows in set (0.036 secs)

OK
```

Comment: do I need to provide where clause always. Also, could you please provide example for truncate.

Comment: updated my response for your question.  Try aql> help  -- has all commands syntax explained.

Comment: Thanks pgupta. One more question why do I get error when the id field is string. Please see my updated question.

Comment: _id is a bin name. you can choose to return specific bins from a record. however you cannot delete a record by its bin. you have delete an entire record using its primary key in this syntax.  see my delete example. if this answers everything, please mark your question as "Answered". Thanks.

Comment: truncate is not working still I get truncate  test.User ;

ERROR: 404: COMMAND NOT FOUND : truncate

Comment: What is your server version? Aerospike introduced truncate in ver 3.12.

Comment: [vagrant@localhost ~]$ asinfo -v "version"  ==>... will print version ...==>   
Aerospike Community Edition build 3.10.1.1

Comment: My aerospike version is `Aerospike Community Edition build 3.15.1.4`

Comment: Can you show the aql output for aql> show namespaces and for aql> show sets ?

Comment: I've updated the details in the question itself. Please let me know if you need more details.

Comment: So your set name is UserRecord. What happens if you do aql> truncate test.UserRecord ?

Comment: Your aql version does not support truncate. Update your tools. https://www.aerospike.com/download/tools/notes.html Tools 3.15.0.3 added truncate.

Comment: Thanks a lot pgupta.